# How to print files to client rollpaper printer from MVC Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, printing, client-side

In my project I came across this problem that I have been struggling for so much hours. Hope somebody could help me.

My client needs to print many tickets from the web (with one click) with some info from the database, let's say Name, Date and Price. All the tickets will be printed on a Rollpaper Printer, so after every ticket it should autocut each one. 
Which would be an appropriate way to achieve this task?

I have a working code, that uses the PrintDocument Class (code below), the problem is that I need to have access to the printer to use it.

Scenario:

- I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 on Visual Studio 2010.
- The app is on a Shared Server.
- Need to generate many tickets that will print all at once.
- **I have access to the Client PC, so I can install everything there and touch whatever is neccesary.**
- The app is used with Firefox and/or Chrome.
- The printer is an Epson TMT82.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static bool PrintTicket(ref string Msg, string Impresora)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument Pd = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            //If empty, Default
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Impresora))
                Pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = Impresora;
            Margins margins = new Margins(10, 0, 0, 0);

            Pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margins;
            Pd.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
            Pd.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printTicket_PrintPage);
            Pd.Print();
            PrintServer ps = new PrintServer();
            PrintQueue printerQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
            SpotTroubleUsingProperties(ref Msg, printerQueue);
            result = (Msg == String.Empty);
            if (!result)
            {
                var jobs = printerQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection();
                foreach (var job in jobs)
                {
                    job.Cancel();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Msg = ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the printer _driver_ (already installed) be able to handle that?

Comment: The problem is that PrintDocument works on the side where it is executed. So it will look for a printer on the server and not on the client.